# Exim backscatter

Tags: linux, email, spam

One of my relays has been listed on backscatter.org, now I'm trying to configure our existing config only to send bounces to local users only. Does anyone knows how I deal with this issue?

I've added following rule in my acl_check_rcpt

```
deny senders = :
    dnslists = ips.backscatterer.org
    log_message = $sender_host_address listed at $dnslist_domain
    message = Backscatter: $dnslist_text
```

Would this be enough not get listed again?

Comment: Did it worked for you this rule?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://slett.net/spam-filtering-for-mx/exim-bounces.html which should hopefully help suggest some options.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make sure that the MTA replies a 5xx code when someone tries to send a message to a user that does not exist on your system. Bounce messages are sent when this information can't be verified (e.g. you are using simple LMTP to deliver the message to your user's mailbox). Instead of limiting bounces to your local users, the system should provide proper responses to MAIL TO commands.